# Show only the last image upload in PHP

Tags: php, image, fancybox

In my website, i made images galleries by themes opening with fancy box, so on my index i want only see the last mini image upload and when i click open all the gallery, but for the moment every mini images i upload are shown, how can i do for see only the last one upload?

this is my php function:

```html
  <?php 
        $villa = "img/travaux/villa/mini";
        $dir = opendir($villa);
        while($file = readdir($dir)){
            $allow_ext = array("jpg",'png','gif');
            $ext = strtolower(substr($file,-3));
            if(in_array($ext,$allow_ext)){
                ?>
  <a rel="single_1" href="img/travaux/villa/<?php echo $file; ?>" title="">   
                    <img src="img/travaux/villa/mini/<?php echo $file; ?>"/> 
        <?php
           }
          }
        
   ?> 
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

found:

```html
<ul class="grid">
        
          <li>
          <?php
          $villa = "img/travaux/villa/mini/";
        $dir = opendir($villa);
        while($file = readdir($dir)){
            $allow_ext = array("jpg",'png','gif');
            $ext = strtolower(substr($file,-3));
            if(in_array($ext,$allow_ext)){
                ?>
            <a href="img/travaux/villa/<?php echo $file; ?>" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="villa">
               <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        
        <?php
   $tabFich = array();
   $iterator = new DirectoryIterator("img/travaux/villa/mini/");
   foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
   if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
   $tabFich[ $fileinfo->getCTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
   }
   }
   ksort( $tabFich);
   $dernierFichier = end( $tabFich );
  ?>
            <img src="img/travaux/villa/mini/<?php echo $dernierFichier; ?>" />
              <div class="text">
                  <p>Construction de villas neuves</p>            
              </div>
                </a>
          </li>
          </ul>
```